# What is the use of the below given tables in Joomla Database?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

What is the use of the below given tables in Joomla Database?

> jos_core_acl_aro
>   jos_core_acl_aro_groups
>   jos_core_acl_aro_map
>   jos_core_acl_aro_sections
>   jos_core_acl_groups_aro_map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACL stands for "Access control list", so probably it has to do with user rights management, who is admin, who is mod etc, what kan and can't they do etc...

**EDIT:** ACL management is a new feature for joomla 1.6 http://docs.joomla.org/ACL_Tutorial_for_Joomla_1.6

Comment: Perfect Catch Moak, But I need the specific definition of each table i have mentioned, please elaborate

Comment: I need More dtails on Database tables specifically

Comment: sorry, if I where you I would google each table separately and check out what comes up, joomla org has a decent documentation

Comment: I did it and didnt find anything specific